# How can I use Python to delete certain paragraphs in docx document?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I have a large .docx document. It has over 100 paragraphs. However, there is some trash paragraph that I need to delete. For example, those paragraphs need to be deleted has a keyword "None". How can I use python to delete those paragraphs have the keyword "None". This is what I have so far, but it can only delete the blank paragraph. How can I modify it to achieve my goal?

```py
import docx

f = docx.Document(r"test.docx")  
doc = docx.Document() 

for para in f.paragraphs:
    if para.text.count("\n") == len(para.text):  
        continue
    else:
        if not para.text[0].isalpha(): 
            continue

    doc.add_paragraph(para.text) 

doc.save(r"test2.docx")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this for the simple case with this code:

```
def delete_paragraph(paragraph):
    p = paragraph._element
    p.getparent().remove(p)
    p._p = p._element = None
```

Any subsequent access to the "deleted" paragraph object will raise AttributeError, so you should be careful not to keep the reference hanging around, including as a member of a stored value of Document.paragraphs.

The reason it's not in the library yet is because the general case is much trickier, in particular needing to detect and handle the variety of linked items that can be present in a paragraph; things like a picture, a hyperlink, or chart etc.

But if you know for sure none of those are present, these few lines should get the job done.

Comment: you should cite the location you copied this from, as acknowledgement of the original author's work.

Comment: How can I modify this code to achieve my goal? Do you have a full example of it?

Comment: as nobody did it, here I link the original place where this info seems to come from: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/33#issuecomment-77661907

Comment: It appears the last line is incorrect according to this github issue: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/33#issuecomment-551891907

Should be `paragraph._p = paragraph._element = None`